# Copy image to another folder and Rename

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem. I wrote this code:

```
$imagesDir = '../gender/male/';
$imagesDir2 = '../uploads/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
$profile_picture = $randomImage;
```

After using a query, the full path gets inserted into the database table.

After the query, i wrote this code:

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");
$select = $select->fetch_object();

if(!empty($select->profile_picture)){
    chmod($randomImage, 0777);
    chmod($imagesDir2, 0777);
    $new_name = pathinfo($randomImage);
    copy($randomImage,$imagesDir2.$new_name['basename']);
    $new_file = md5(mt_rand()).$new_name['basename'];
    chmod ($imagesDir2.$new_name['basename'], 0777);
    rename($imagesDir2.$new_name['basename'],$imagesDir2.$new_file);
    chmod('../gender/male/' . $new_name['basename'], 0777);
    unlink('../gender/male/' . $new_name['basename']);
    $db->query("UPDATE users SET profile_picture='".$new_file."' WHERE email='".$email."'");
}
```

I just can't get it to work. What i want it to do,

1. copy the image to the uploads folder
2. rename the image in the uploads folder by using a md5(mt_rand()) before the image name (e.g. md5(mt_rand())1.jpg)
3. update this in the database
4. unlink/destroy the original which was in the '../gender/male/' folder

the only thing that doesn't work is unlinking. file is still in the folder.

I hope someone can help me on this. And to all who put efford in helping out, i would like to thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i would like to thank myself for all my help. Second of all, for all future readers who are stuck with a simular problem. I changed the if statement to:

```
if(!empty($select->profile_picture)){
    chmod($imagesDir2, 0777);
    $new_name = pathinfo($randomImage);
    copy($randomImage,$imagesDir2.$new_name['basename']);
    $new_file = md5(mt_rand()).$new_name['basename'];
    chmod ($imagesDir2.$new_name['basename'], 0777);
    rename($imagesDir2.$new_name['basename'],$imagesDir2.$new_file);
    chmod($imagesDir.$new_name['basename'], 0777);
    unlink($imagesDir.$new_name['basename']);
    $db->query("UPDATE users SET profile_picture='".$new_file."' WHERE email='".$email."'");
}
```

it works. Make sure you have the right permission settings. I hope it helps you solve your problem.